# VARCHAR2(1000) limited to 100 chars only

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

When trying to store in an Oracle SQL table a string of more than 100 chars, while the field limitation is 1000 bytes which I understood is ~1000 English chars, I'm getting out of bounds exception:

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3`

What might be the cause for this low limitation?

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

The code where the error occurs is (see [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118875/discussion-between-jonathon-ogden-and-batman)):

```
// Commenting the existing code, because for sensitive information
// toString returns masked data
int nullSize = 5;
int i = 0;

// removing '[' and ']', signs and fields with 'null' value and also add
// ';' as delimiter.
while (i != -1) {
    int index1 = str.indexOf('[', i);
    int index2 = str.indexOf(']', i + 1);
    i = index2;
    if (index2 != -1 && index1 != -1) {
        int index3 = str.indexOf('=', index1);
        if (index3 + nullSize > str.length() || !str.substring(index3 + 1, index3 + nullSize).equals("null")) {
            String str1 = str.substring(index1 + 1, index2);
            concatStrings = concatStrings.append(str1);
            concatStrings = concatStrings.append(";");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share whatever SQL you are using to insert this string into your Oracle table as that error is about indexing into a string, not data truncation because of being inserted into a column with a data type that is too small to represent your data. Not only that, but field limitations of 1000 bytes does not necessarily mean 1000 characters as it depends on character encoding.

Comment: @JonathonOgden: got no access as of now for the inserted query, but if the encoding is UTF-8, will it be a limitation that low of only 100 English chars under 1000Bytes ?

Comment: How are you getting this exception? What is it you are doing exactly?

Comment: This is a column which represents a note field, and when this field is exceeded the 100 chars, it throws this exception, if it is below 100 chars, no exception will be thrown... and text encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: What code or Oracle application are you using to insert this data?

Comment: The data is sending to the table using Java core methods with SQL query in it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118875/discussion-between-jonathon-ogden-and-batman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when the string to store in a `varchar` field is too long, it is cropped silently. Anyway when there is an error message, it is generally specific. The error seems to be related to a operation on a string (`String.substring()`?).

Furthermore, even when the string is encoded in UTF-8, the ratio characters/bytes shouldn't be that low.

You really should put the code sample where your error occurs in you question and the string causing this and also have a closer look  at the stacktrace to see where the error occurs.

From the code you posted in your [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118875/discussion-between-jonathon-ogden-and-batman), I can see this line of code :

```
String str1 = str.substring(index1 + 1, index2);
```

You check that index1 and index2 are different than -1 but you don't check if  `(index1 + 1) >= index2` which makes your code crash.

Try this with `str = "*]ab=null["` (which length is under 100 characters) but you can also get the error with a longer string such as `"osh]] [ = null ]Clipers: RRR was removed by user and customer called in to have it since it was an RRT"`.

**Once again the size of the string doesn't matter, only the content!!!**

You can reproduce your problem is a closing square bracket (`]`) before an opening one(`[`) and between them an equal sign (`=`) followed (directly or not) by the `"null"` string.

Comment: Ok, got it, but y it fails for strings below 100 chars only ?! :(

Comment: @Batman Are you sure? Isn't it a simple coincidence? Once again, please mention the value of `str`

Comment: value is: "Josh]]] Clipers: RRR was removed by user and customer called in to have it since it was an RRT" it is a string value a human entered through a GUI and only when >100 chars it fails.... otherwise it will be no OOB exception :(

Comment: @Batman the value you gave is only 94 chars long and nothing wrong happens when you process it. What is the value when you get the error? Don't you log it?

Comment: @Batman Anyway, It doesn't fail only for string small than 100 chars. **Size doesn't matter in this case! Only the values of ´index1` and `index2`do!!!**. Try with`osh]] [ = null ]Clipers: RRR was removed by user and customer called in to have it since it was an RRT "`

Comment: do u think it is the parenthesis that makes the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jonathon Ogden "limitations of 1000 bytes does not necessarily mean 1000 characters as it depends on character encoding".

I recommend you to Alter column in your Oracle table from VARCHAR2(1000 Byte) to VARCHAR2(1000 Char).

Comment: But in UTF-8, what will be the limitation when talking about 1000bytes ?

Comment: If there is a 1000 byte limit on the column and you're using UTF-8 encoding, then 100 English characters should not be a problem at all. I believe UTF-8 is encoded anywhere between 1 to 4 bytes per character, so you're well within the 1000 byte limit with 100 English characters.

Comment: But when you are using ']' or '[' will it be significantly growth ? or lets say when someone writes in Cyrillic letters like it was English ?